# Testing whether an org is available for deployment

Tags: metadata-api, ant

Are there any command line methods (Linux/Metadata API'ish) that will tell you if an org is available to be deployed to? I'm assuming an org can only have one deployment at a time via the Metadata api, so I'm looking for a command line method to tell me whether or not I can deploy to that org.

Edit: I know you can retrieve deployment status assuming you know the deployment ID. I'm looking to do this without knowing any deployment IDs, just the org id.

Comment: An org can have multiple deployments. only one active at a time the rest will be in pending status. Not a synchronous process

Comment: Any way to pull the deployment IDs  and know which is active and which are pending?

Comment: Did you bother to read the docs? I will put just as much effort into my answer - yes there is

Comment: Gee that's helpful Eric. I read the docs and didn't find anything obvious -- and that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Maybe you did not read the right doc? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_checkdeploystatus.htm

Comment: If you do not know the deployment id follow instructions here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm